# Rewrite ucwords strtolower

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to make a rewrite rule to do this?

My php files all have first character uppercase and some may have a hyphen
like
Filename.php and File-Name.php

firstly

```
# Try this rewrite only if the file is not found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Then I want to make a rule for a request like

```
mysite.com/thing
mysite.com/Thing
mysite.com/THING
```

rewrites to the real file at

```
mysite.com/Thing.php
```

or (with the hyphens)

```
mysite.com/another-thing
mysite.com/Another-Thing
mysite.com/ANOTHER-THING
```

rewrites to the real file at

```
mysite.com/Another-Thing.php
```

Then if the file is STILL not found, give up and re-write the error to index.php i.e

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [R=301,L]
```

I can think of a way to do this in php though not sure if it could be done in rewrite e.g.

```
$url = str_replace('-', ' ', $url);
$url = ucwords(strtolower($url));
$url = str_replace(' ', '-', $url) . ".php";
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can do this inside a rewrite but *only if* you have root access to the server configuration -- using a directive called RewriteMap.  However you can't use this if you only have `.htaccess` access to the rewrite engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following declaration to your apache or vhost config file:

```
 RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

And then the following rule either in the same file or in `.htaccess` files can operate on strings using this map function, for example

```
 RewriteRule ^                        -       [E=LC_URI:${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}}]
```

And now you can use `%{ENV:LC_URI}` in your rewrite rules, or if you want to remove the leading /:

```
 RewriteCond   ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}}   ^/(.*)$
 RewriteRule   ^.*                    %1      [E=LC_FILE:%1]
```

etc.